# Eliminate any in Generic of Typescript Class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to eliminate the `any` type in the following minimal example. The `tables` property in the `Database` class is a map having `Table<any>` for its value type. However, I want to limit `Table<any>` to `Table<? extends Tuple>` but do not know how to do.

```js
class Database {
    private readonly tables = new Map<string, Table<any>>();

    getTable<T extends Tuple>(id: string): Table<T> {
        if (this.tables.has(id)) return this.tables.get(id)!;
        return this.createTable(id);
    }

    private createTable<T extends Tuple>(id: string): Table<T> {
        const created = new FakeTable(id)
        this.tables.set(id, created);
        return created;
    }
}

class FakeTable<T extends Tuple> implements Table<T> {

    constructor(id: string) {}

    queryAll() { return [] }
    insert(tuples: T[]) {}
    delete(tuples: T[]) {}
}

interface Table<T extends Tuple> {
    queryAll(): T[];
    insert(tuples: T[]): void
    delete(tuples: T[]): void
}

type Tuple = Record<string, string | number>;
```

I have tried:

```js
class Database<D> {
    private readonly tables = new Map<string, Table<D extends Tuple>>();
...
```

But TypeScript compiler complains that `'?' expected.(1005)`.

```js
private readonly tables = new Map<string, Table<D extends Tuple>>();
                                                     //        ^
                                                     //  '?' expected.(1005)
```

You can find the minimal example for the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwCNIFNoG8BQ0-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-kmlutYwNeUTQWTqYxCBYBG9pOe0AASmgbkRaFIBfIlId5NAAD78TwU5CS7RGIA).

Comment: what is your goal here? if you use the D from database all your tables would have the same type is that what you want? you would need to use class Database<D extends Tuple> {

Comment: To @L.A and @DigitalDrifter, I do not want to make all my tables from the same database have the same type. Thus, the Codesandbox example @DigitalDrifter provided is not a feasible solution. My goal is just to confine generic to avoid `any` if there is any possible way. Thank you.

Comment: i don't fully understand why if you don't want to use any use unknown.

Comment: You would need to have a type which is the union of all possible Tuple types in your database.  The Database class itself doesn't have any other way of knowing what types of tables it contains.